# Android: display BroadcastReceiver in ListView

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I created a broadcast receiver to follow my Wi-Fi, I'm getting normaly information in LogCat, but I couldn't put the data in a ListView, like I wan't.
I put a ListView example to test it in the `onReceive` method but I didn't work, and I'm having this error:

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(Wifi.Receiver, int, int,
>   String[]) is undefined

This is my code:

```
public class Wifi extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
WifiManager wifi;
Button      enab;
String resultsString ; 
String[] myStringArray;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
ListView listView ;
            // Get ListView object from xml
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                         "Adapter implementation",
                                         "Simple List View In Android",
                                         "Create List View Android", 
                                         "Android Example", 
                                         "List View Source Code", 
                                         "List View Array Adapter", 

                                        };
//getting this error : The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Wifi.Receiver, int, int, //String[]) is undefined           
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

PS: when I put the code of the ListView in the `onCreate` method it worked normaly, but I want it in the `onReceive` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `this` does not refer to Activity Context.

Use

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Wifi.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Look at the constructor

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)

Added in API level 1 Constructor

Parameters 

context             The current context. 
resourc             The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views. 
textViewResourceId  The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated 
objects             The objects to represent in the ListView.
```

So the first param is a valid context

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context // see context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity // see activity
```

And your class extends Activity

```
public class Wifi extends Activity
```

Hence use `Wifi.this` as a valid context.

Comment: still 2 minutes ,and i'll accept ,you just edited (i can accept answer after 7 minutes :) )

Comment: @Amina i understand. its the site's limit and do check the edited answer. You will know why i used `Wifi.this`